# I want to click on a Wincontrol that is not visible in the window using Coded UI

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a Wincontrol that is not visible in the window,i have to drag on the scroll bar to make it visible. How can I use coded UI to access the wincontrol

Comment: Can you not use coded UI to drag on the scrollbar so the control becomes visible, and then test the now visible control?

Comment: Have you tried EnsureClickable().

Comment: Have you tried SetFocus()?

Answer (score 0):

If SetFocus doesnt work then you can move the scroll bar until the control is visiable like how Ralt suggests. I resolved a simlar issue using the following example. The code will click the scroll bar slightly above it's bottom most point. Click as many times as needed.

```
    public void ScrollSlide(UITestControl scrollBar)
    {
        Point bottomOfScrollBar = new Point(scrollBar.Left + (scrollBar.Width / 2), scrollBar.Top + (scrollBar.Height - (scrollBar.Height / 20)

        Mouse.Move(null, new Point(scrollBar.Left + (scrollBar.Width / 2), scrollBar.Top + (scrollBar.Height - (scrollBar.Height / 15))));
        Mouse.Move(null, bottomOfScrollBar )));
        Mouse.DoubleClick(null, bottomOfScrollBar ))));
        Mouse.DoubleClick(null, bottomOfScrollBar )));
        Mouse.DoubleClick(null, bottomOfScrollBar )));
    }
```

Comment: I will try this one. setfocus() doesnt work.. thanx all

Answer (score 0):

Take the below piece of javascript and insert it before your click command (set the scroll height to how high you want it from the very bottom of the page, in my case I am using 5). This is really not the best or most practical way to code but this is far more convenient and works far more often than other coded solutions.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 5)");
```

This should work and shouldn't require you to add any more references or create any new variables - however make sure you change the `_driver` variable to your variable!

most probably "browser", if not or you don't know what variable to use, it would be best use the windows system command. hope this helps.